# WSDLException : An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate a proxy class from a local WSDL file with eclipse Galileo and axis 2 1.4 on windows xp . My problem is that i get an error due to an imported schema inside the WSDL . The line tha troubles me is :

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"/>
```

I've tried to run the wsdl2java following command:

```
wsdl2java.bat  -uri SOAService.wsdl -o D:\temp p test -d xmlbeans -a -s -ns2p -uw
```

and I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException
: Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerat
ionEngine.java:156)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:ty
pes/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve sche
ma referenced at 'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime', relative to 'file:/D:/Prog
rammi/axis2-1.4/bin/SOAService.wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection tim
ed out: connect
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.readInTheWSDLFile(
CodeGenerationEngine.java:288)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerat
ionEngine.java:111)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:520)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:470)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:231)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:304)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:813)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:765)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:690)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:934)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

I suspect it's due to the system proxy which doesn't let retrieve the xsd to the wsdl2java tool. In fact i can download the file from the browser without problems.

There's an option to specify a proxy to wsdl2java or someone has resolved this issue ?
For the moment i've downloaded the XSD, added it to the project and changed the WSDL to include the relative file (instead of the remote one) , but i'd prefer to avoid this , because the file is a third party service WSDL.

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I had the same problem and below is how I solved it using java `-D` option

```
java -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost={value} -Dhttp.proxyPort={value} org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java {wsdlURL}
```

See if it helps you. Regards

Comment: hi praveena, with 6 month of delay i thank you for your answer

Comment: What are the values you are passing in proxy host and port ? how to fix this one by using maven comand?

Answer (score 2):

This solution may not work asis depending on the user's installation. There is no mention in the solution of the -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts={list of hosts to exclude} option which may be required if your server running the webservices is local and there are references to xml files hosted outside your environment or if your proxy is not setup to answer local requests.